# Member <Method> cannot be used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in Unity and I need to get the camera of an object using a script, the code I used was this:

```
Camera cam = GameObject.FindWithTag("string").GetComponent<Camera>();
```

However, I get this message

> Member GameObject.FindWithTag(String) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; quality it with a type name instead

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera1;
    public Camera cam2;

    [SerializeField]
    public  GameObject[] cams;
    

    PosicionamientoDeObjetos mensajero;
    public GameObject objetoActalCam;

   Color colorencam = new Color(5,4,2,0.5f);

    private Camera Hola;
    // Start is called before the first frame update        

    void Start()
    {
        camera1.enabled=true;
        cam2.enabled=false;

       
    }

    void cambiocamara()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q)) {
          cam2.enabled=false;
          camera1.enabled=true;
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {
          camera1.enabled = false;
          cam2.enabled = true;
        }
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        

        cambiocamara();
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            mensajero = FindObjectOfType<PosicionamientoDeObjetos>();
            mensajero.Prefabs[0].GetComponent<Camera>();
            Coger();
            Debug.Log(cam2);
        }
    }

    public void ObtenerCamara(){
         Hola = objetoActalCam.FindWithTag("CameraSecond").GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you perhaps named a variable/field `GameObject` somewhere close to the line you've shown is? We really need a [mcve] to be able to help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`FindWithTag` method receive a string as parameter, and you are passing the String type itself, instead of a variable of string type.

So try with quotes, **"** String **"** instead of simply String:

```
Camera cam = GameObject.FindWithTag("String").GetComponent<Camera>();
```

**Edit**:
After your question edition the problem is revealed, you are not calling

```
Camera cam = GameObject.FindWithTag("string").GetComponent<Camera>();
```

like you typed in your question. Instead you are calling it like:

```
Camera cam = gameObjectVariable.FindWithTag("string").GetComponent<Camera>();
```

You have to call it with `GameObject` type, not with a `gameObject` variable

Comment: Ah, but that was just an example, my real code is like this (Cam1 is already declared) Cam1 = CurrentObject.FindWithTag("SecondCamera"). GetComponent<Camera>();

And it doesn't work for me :c

Comment: Then post your exact code and error log message, or it will be hard to solve it

Comment: @JonathanMurilloJaramillo you are calling FindObjectWithTag from a variable, not the type GameObject, so instead of using objetoActalCam.FindeObjectWithTag(), use GameObject.FindObjectWithTag()

Comment: My god! You're a genius, thank you very much, my code works, you're the best

Comment: @JonathanMurilloJaramillo you're welcome, remember to mark and upvote the correct answer (mine or Damien answer is also correct) so other users can see it as solved ^^

Answer (score 0):

`objetoActalCam` is an *instance* of `GameObject`.

The error message tells you:

> Member `GameObject.FindWithTag(String)` cannot be accessed with an instance reference; quality it with a type name instead

So, follow it's advice:

```
public void ObtenerCamara(){
     Hola = GameObject.FindWithTag("CameraSecond").GetComponent<Camera>();
}
```

(Which, ironically, is pretty close to the code you originally presented us with)